# UIImage transparent with shape

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, transparent, alpha

In my iPhone app I have two UIImageViews that are circles.
I used this code for that:

```
manPic.layer.cornerRadius=manPic.frame.size.width/2;
manPic.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
womanPic.layer.cornerRadius=womanPic.frame.size.width/2;
womanPic.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
```

the two circles have some area of overlapping, and I want this area only to be half transparent such that the user can see the two images together. 
this area is not a square (it's pretty obvious  because it's circles we're talking about).

do you have any idea how I can do it?

Comment: You want only the overlapping area to be transparent?

Comment: yes. only this area. the rest should be normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do want only the overlapping area to be transparent, you probably have to draw your images via coregraphics with pretty much masking logic.

But an idea without the need of custom drawing code (in case the color of the surrounding view is a single solid color). Put both images on your view. Than add another square sized view on top of the images to "mask" the overlapping area. Enable clipping `.clipsToBounds = YES` for that view. Add the two images again to that view and set their `.alpha` to `0.5` (or what you want) each.

So structure would be:

```
mainview
-> imageView
-> imageView
-> masking view (clipsToBounds=YES, backgroundColor=mainview.backgroundColor)
    -> imageView with alpha
    -> imageView with alpha
```